# Running phpunit tests using HHVM (HipHop)

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, hhvm

I am trying to run PHPUnit unit tests via HHVM on a virtual Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit Server) install. The tests usually run using a phpunit.xml file located in my tests directory, which includes a bootstrap file to handle autoloading, and the tests run fine on an ordinary php install. However, I keep getting:

```
HipHop Fatal error: File not found: File/Iterator/Autoload.php in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 64
```

When running:

```
hhvm -f /usr/bin/phpunit /path/to/my/testsDirectory/SomeTest.php
```

And I haven't been able to figure out how to run phpunit under hhvm using a bootstrap or config file... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to ensure that PEAR is in your include path and you have the PEAR php-file-iterator package installed.

Comment: Without knowing your complete setup, the path comment above may indeed be correct (I have seen other SO questions that have given a similar response). For how I setup my PHPUnit testing with HHVM, you can go here: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/OSS-PHP-Frameworks-Unit-Testing:-General

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### HHVM 2.4+

HHVM 2.4.0 was just [released](http://www.hhvm.com/blog/3287/hhvm-2-4-0) and it came with full phpunit support! Just give the full path to phpunit binary, like this:

```
$ hhvm /usr/bin/phpunit
```

Cheers!

---

### HHVM 2.3

Tested this step by step guide from HHVM [wiki](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/OSS-PHP-Frameworks-Unit-Testing%3a-General#phpunit) and it works. Here is a simplified guide:

On your project, add the following entries to your composer.json file:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.*",
    "phpunit/php-invoker": "1.1.3",
    "phpunit/dbunit": "1.2.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": "1.3.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit-story": "1.0.2"
}
```

1. Run `hhvm composer.phar install --dev`. If you did a composer system wide install, run `hhvm /usr/local/bin/composer install --dev`, it works too.
2. A vendor directory will be created. The phpunit "binary" will be located at `vendor/bin/phpunit`
3. To run PHPUnit for your project: `hhvm vendor/bin/phpunit [optional arguments]`

> Note: Probably in a not so distant future `hhvm /usr/local/bin/phpunit
>   [optional arguments]` will work as expected, but right now this is the
>   easiest option we have

Comment: `vendor/bin/phpunit` is now an `sh` script, so you have to run `hhvm vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit` to make it work!

Comment: `[optional arguments]` still doesn't work in PHPUnit 5.7

Answer (score 5):

Just a note to add to @cabbey's asnwer: you can set the `IncludeSearchPaths` value using the `-v` option:

```shell
hhvm -v Server.IncludeSearchPaths.share=/usr/share/php/ $(which phpunit) MyTests.php
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to configure HHVM to include the PEAR libraries in it's search paths.

I added this to my config.hdf's Server section:

```
    IncludeSearchPaths {
        forphpunit = /usr/lib/php/
    }
```

and then ran phpunit as:

```
hhvm -c ~/config.hdf /usr/bin/phpunit --bootstrap bootstrap.php MyTests.php
```