# phpunit with HHVM 3.11

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, hhvm

Following the accepted answer to [Running phpunit tests using HHVM (HipHop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032312/running-phpunit-tests-using-hhvm-hiphop#), I attempted to run some tests:

```
unit-tests/ [develop] > hhvm $(which phpunit) --colors -c phpunit.xml --testsuite all .

/usr/bin/env php -d allow_url_fopen=On -d detect_unicode=Off /usr/local/Cellar/phpunit/4.3.4/libexec/phpunit-4.3.4.phar $*
```

It appears that this is a command to run the tests (which it does), but I'm confused about

1. why it's printing this command instead of just running the tests
2. whether executing that command even uses HHVM, since it starts with `/usr/bin/env php`...

Does anyone have any insight into this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened here is that you installed PHPUnit using homebrew, so it created a wrapper script for the actual PHAR file. That wrapper script is a Bash script that runs the PHPUnit PHAR and that script is what you're trying to get HHVM to run. Since it's not a PHP or Hack script, the Bash script is outputted directly.

Instead, you probably want to try to execute `$(brew --prefix phpunit)/libexec/phpunit*.phar`

e.g.: `hhvm $(brew --prefix phpunit)/libexec/phpunit*.phar --colors -c phpunit.xml --testsuite all .`

The wildcard is so that you don't need to specify the version of PHPUnit being using.

Comment: Thanks! So helpful :)